# Playing a video from IsolatedStorage

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm currently playing video by using the MediaLauncher like this:

```
var launcher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();
launcher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;
launcher.Media = new Uri("shared/transfers/video.mp4", UriKind.Relative);
launcher.Show();
```

But this has the problem that it closes when you switch to another app or lock the screen, so I wanted to create a page in the app to play the video instead, so I can keep the state.

I tried using both MediaElement and Microsoft Player Framework like this:

```
var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
var stream = file.OpenFile("shared/transfers/video.mp4", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
mediaPlayer.SetSource(stream);
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

and like this:

```
mediaPlayer.Source = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/shared/transfers/video.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

but in all the 4 cases I get a not very helpful `3123 An error has occurred.` error message on the `MediaFailed` event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem, turns out I didn't have the `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PLAYBACK` capability set. I got it to work with MMF with this code:

```
var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
var stream = file.OpenFile("shared/transfers/video.mp4", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
mediaPlayer.SetSource(stream);
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

The url versions didn't work